# How to add class to a passed Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When trying to pass a component as a prop of another component, everything works fine.
But if i want instead pass a Component and handle its css classes inside the children, I'm currently lost.

In my mind im trying to achieve something similar to this:

```
import Navbar from 'what/ever/path/Navbar/is/in/Navbar.js';

export default function ParentComponent {
  return(
     <Navbar NavIcon={<MyIcon/>} />
  )
}
```

```
.... Imports etc...

export default function Navbar(props) {
  const {NavIcon} = props;
  return(
    <Navigation>
        // Now use the Prop as a Component and pass default classNames to it.
        // So that we don't need to wrap everything inside a span / div etc.
       <NavIcon className="AddCustomStylesAlwaysHere" />
   </Navigation>

  )
}
```

Comment: What about `NavIcon={MyIcon}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches come to my mind:

### Passing a component

Just pass the component and let the parent take care of its instantiation. This way, the only changes you need is making sure `<MyIcon />` accepts a `className` prop:

```
const MyIcon = ({ className }) => {
  return <div className={className} />
};

const Navbar = ({ NavIcon }) => {
  return (
    <Navigation>
      <NavIcon className="AddCustomStylesAlwaysHere" />
    </Navigation>
  );
};

<Navbar NavIcon={MyIcon} />
```

### Passing an element instance

This way, you take care of instantiating the component and the parent just renders it. In this case, you have to use React utilities to modify existing elements (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement):

```
const MyIcon = ({ className }) => {
  return <div className={className} />
};

const Navbar = ({ NavIcon }) => {
  return (
    <Navigation>
      {React.cloneElement(NavIcon, { className: 'AddCustomStylesAlwaysHere' })}
    </Navigation>
  );
};

<Navbar NavIcon={<MyIcon />} />
```

Comment: I would tried the second approach by passing an element instance because I like to keep the styling as a work of the children. But somehow I always get this error. **Error: React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed undefined.**  Here is the log of the element as an Image [link](https://ibb.co/FskdGJY).

Comment: @K.Kröger Without seeing your full code is difficult to know what can be causing that error. Make sure you're correctly using the right prop name and if that doesn't help, try using a `console.log` before `React.cloneElement`. Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-chandrasekhar-ihnqn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think I miss understood your example, I thought I was possible to set the class from within the Navbar Component. But what you did was that you assigned everything from the parent component and passed everything down to the child. Im going to try to set up a example of my situation inside a codesandbox

Comment: I created a codesandbox example, and it worked.  So I inspected my code again and found out was the issue was, I called the Accordion twice, once where I passed the Icon Compoent as a Prop and the other one where I did not. A good Example for the usecase of Default Props :)  Thank you very much. [Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-mirzakhani-5ct9n?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React.Children.map` in combination with [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement):

```
{
    React.Children.map(children, ( child, idx ) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, { className: 'additional-classnames' })
    })
}
```

Comment: I think doing it this way, would actually not be so good because you would apply all additional-classnames to every child.